# In Powershell, how do I delete a file with a hyphen (dash) in the filename?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, when I try to delete a file with a hyphen in the nam like this:

```
remove-item 'C:\S3\op_netadmin-47.bak'
```

I get this error:

```
remove-item : Cannot remove item C:\S3\op_netadmin-47.bak: Access to the path 'C:\S3\op_netadmin-47.bak' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-item 'C:\S3\op_netadmin-47.bak'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\S3\op_netadmin-47.bak:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

But if I rename the file to op_netadmin_47.bak, it works fine.

I've tried with and without double quotes as well as single quotes

Comment: There's nothing special about hyphens (`-`) in a file name per se, so the problem may be permissions-related. If the `ReadOnly` attribute is set, try `-Force`.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the hyphen in the filename, as it's properly displayed in the error message. The problem is either that the file is in use, or that you don't have rights to delete files in that directory. Read the actual words in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your file name with `-` and `_`, both work ok. I also tried to use `"` around file name which also works.

As  @mklement0 mentioned in comments read-only files require `-Force` parameter

Make sure user running script has read/write access to given folder